# Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to learn react js with redux.

This is my View.js

```
export default HomeView

//Import React
import React from 'react'

//Import Redux Components
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

//Import Action
import { addAcct, upsertAccts, qryAccts, updateAccts } from '../../Counter/modules/counter';

class HomeView extends React.Component {
  constructor (props)
  {
    super(props);
  }
  componentWillMount()
  {
    this.props.dispatch(qryAccts());
    console.log(this.props);
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
  componentDidMount()
  {
    console.log('----Did----',this.props.accts);
  }
  //Perform Upsert Actions
  upsertAccts(e)
  {
    this.props.dispatch(upsertAccts(this.props.accts))
  }

  //Add new Account to the Array
  addAcct(event)
  {
    this.props.dispatch(addAcct());
    console.log('===this.props===',this.props);
  }


  //onChange function to handle when a name is changed
  handleChange(ev,index)
  {
    this.props.dispatch(updateAccts(ev.target.value,index));
  }

  dateChange(e)
  {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('-----this.props.accts-------',this.props.accts);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Accounts</h1>
        <ul>
         { this.props.accts.map((v,i) => <li key={i}><input style={{width:'500px'}} onChange={event => this.handleChange(event,i)} value={v.Name}/></li>) }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//Connects Redux State to React, Injects reducer as a property
//export default Page1Demo;
export default connect(state => ({ accts: state.accts }))(HomeView);
```

And my reducer action here

```
// ------------------------------------
// Constants
// ------------------------------------


export const RECEIVED_ACCTS = 'RECEIVED_ACCTS';
export const UPSERT_ACCTS = 'UPSERT_ACCTS';
export const ADD_ACCT = 'ADD_ACCT';
export const UPDATE_ACCTS = 'UPDATE_ACCTS';


// ------------------------------------
// Actions
// ------------------------------------
export function recAccts(accts) {
  console.log('------16----',accts);
  return{
    type: RECEIVED_ACCTS,
    accts: accts
  }
}

export function qryAccts()
{
  return dispatch => {
    ResponsiveCtrl.getAccts(function(r, e) {
      console.log('------26----',r);
      console.log('------26----',e);
      dispatch(recAccts(r))
    },{escape:false});
  }
}

export function upsertAccts(acctStore) {
  return dispatch => {
    ResponsiveCtrl.upsertAccts(acctStore, function(r, e) {
      dispatch(recAccts(r))
    },{escape:false});
  }
}

export function addAcct() {
  return {
    type: ADD_ACCT
  }
}

export function updateAccts(name,index) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_ACCTS,
    acctName:name,
    listIndex:index
  }
}

/*  This is a thunk, meaning it is a function that immediately
    returns a function for lazy evaluation. It is incredibly useful for
    creating async actions, especially when combined with redux-thunk!

    NOTE: This is solely for demonstration purposes. In a real application,
    you'd probably want to dispatch an action of COUNTER_DOUBLE and let the
    reducer take care of this logic.  */



// ------------------------------------
// Action Handlers
// ------------------------------------

// ------------------------------------
// Reducer
// ------------------------------------
const initialState = [];

//Reducer function
export function accts(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log('==action===',action);
  console.log('==initialState===',initialState);
  console.log('==state===',state);
  switch (action.type) {
  case RECEIVED_ACCTS:
  //Return the Accouts we receive from Salesforce
    state = action.accts;
    return state;
  case UPDATE_ACCTS:
  //Update our array at the specific index
    var newState = state.slice();
    newState[action.listIndex].Name = action.acctName;
    return newState;
  case ADD_ACCT:
  //Add a new Account to our Array
    var newState = state.slice();
    newState.push({Name:""});
    return newState;
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

I am able to determine the issue but not sure how to fix the issue.

Issue is dom is generated first and I am getting the values later that's why my map is empty initially and it is giving me error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Any idea how to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: in connect function, can you please print whole state and show me structure of state?

Comment: @steppefox can you pls let me know how to add debug there. I am trying to add but getting syntax errors

Comment: export default connect((state) => {
  console.log(state);
  return { accts: state.accts };
})(HomeView);

Comment: @steppefox I have added the scrennshot for debug logs pls check it is coming accts

Comment: Your store doesn't contain acts data, i think your reducer isn't connected to store. How do you create your store? Do you use something like combineReducers?

Comment: @steppefox  Can we chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117281/discussion-between-ratan-and-damon

Answer (score 0):

Break that code into its own method with a validation on `this.props.accts`.

```
...

renderAccts () {
  if (Array.isArray(this.props.accts)) {
    return this.props.accts.map((v,i) => <li key={i}><input style={{width:'500px'}} onChange={event => this.handleChange(event,i)} value={v.Name}/></li>)
  }
  return ''
},

render () {
...
<div>
  <h1>Accounts</h1>
  <ul>
    {this.renderAccts()}
  </ul>
</div>
}
```

This is good practice to begin with, because you want to ensure that you are getting exactly what you expect from `props`, but it will also let you debug further if it turns out that your initial assumption is not the cause of the problem. You can now easily add a `console.log(this.props.accts)` before the map and see what's going on. This method will be called every time you receive new props (which triggers render). If that prop is undefined the first time render is called, you will get this error if you try to map over it. If the problem persists, even with this validation, you should ensure you are ever actually getting the prop you expect.

Comment: this took me to another error, now I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` ?

Comment: not sure looks like it is unable to bind the value to variable

Comment: If you are using chrome console, the error will show up in red, and on the right hand side you can click a link to the offending line, or expand for a stack trace. This is very helpful for debugging :)

Comment: I am not how should i help you to debug.. this is screenshot i took http://i.imgur.com/UlEjemJ.png I can't see any link at right side

Comment: hey sorry my miss. now no error but I have added debug in `renderAccts ` in method but got list is undefined.. after underfined I have added debug in `qryAccts` this method lino no 26 there i am getting the debugs

Comment: If you're using a `debugger` rather than `console.log` you won't get the result you expect due to transpiling. When you say `list` do you mean `this.props.accts`? I'll be happy to try and help you out, but I have to go to sleep since it's 3am for me. Feel free to PM me, otherwise I'll check back tomorrow. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117281/discussion-between-ratan-and-damon).

Comment: Damon no issue. we can check at your morning this is not urgent I am just trying to learn ReactJs with redux my own. ok good night catch you later